# Issue querying related data in Apollo Server 4 with Prisma Schema

Tags: graphql, prisma, apollo-server

I am using Apollo Server 4 and Prisma 5 to build a simple ecomm project. At the moment I am trying to set up my resolvers to be able to bidirectionally query for Users + their comments...and also query Comments as the top level and return it's associated user. In the database `Comment` table has an associated `user_id` FK relationship to the `User` table. `User` table does NOT have a comments id, thus a one -> many and many -> one relationship.

When I try to query a user, comments is `null` unless I write a separate resolver for it and then use Prisma orm to `include` the relationship. I don't want to follow this as it seems like an antipattern when using gql. What I want to accomplish is to have a `userByEmail()` resolver in my top level `Query{}` from my SDL...and then have a `Comment: {}` 2nd level object in my resolvers to then have the corresponding `User` be the `parent` argument coming in the resolver...this is more gql dependant than db dependant.

Relevant Prisma Models:

```
model User {
  id          String        @id @default(uuid())
  username    String        @unique
  email       String        @unique
  password    String
  first_name  String
  last_name   String?
  created_at  DateTime      @default(now())
  updated_at  DateTime      @updatedAt
  deleted     Boolean       @default(false)
  comments    Comment[]
  ratings     Rating[]
  orders      Order[]
  UserAddress UserAddress[]
}


model Comment {
  id         String        @id @default(uuid())
  user       User     @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id    String   // Change type to String
  product    Product  @relation(fields: [product_id], references: [id])
  product_id String
  content    String
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  deleted    Boolean  @default(false)
}
```

Relevant schema.graphql types:

```
type Query {
  "Get a user by their email"
  userByEmail(email: String): User!
}

"This type represents a user in the system"
type User {
  "Unique identifier for the user"
  id: ID!

  "Username for login"
  username: String!

  "User's email address"
  email: String!

  "User's first name"
  first_name: String!

  "User's last name (optional)"
  last_name: String!

  "List of comments authored by the user (optional)"
  comments: [Comment]

  "List of ratings created by the user (optional)"
  ratings: [Rating]

  "List of orders placed by the user (optional)"
  orders: [Order]

  "List of user's addresses"
  addresses: [Address]
}

type Comment {
  "Unique identifier for the comment"
  id: ID!

  "Content of the comment"
  content: String!

  "User who authored the comment"
  user: User

  "Product this comment is associated with"
  product: Product
}
```

resolvers.ts

```
import { getUserByEmail, getCommentsByUserId } from '../../dataAccessLayer/orm/user';
import { User } from '../../generated/types';

// Use intersection type to combine Resolvers and Query
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    userByEmail: async (_parent: unknown, { email }: { email: string }) => {
      console.log('parent', email);
      const user = await getUserByEmail(email); // Already includes comments
      return user;
    },
  },
  Comment: {
    userComments: (parent: User) => {
      console.log('parent', parent);
      const userId = parent.id;
      return getCommentsByUserId(userId);
    },
  },
};
```

ORM DB Queries

```
import prisma from '../prismaClient';

export async function getUserByEmail(email: string) {
  return await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email,
    },
  });
}

export async function getCommentsByUserId(id: string) {
  return await prisma.comment.findMany({
    where: {
      user_id: id,
    },
    include: {
      user: true, // Include user relation
    },
  });
}
```

When I run my project I get this error:

```
 Error: Comment.userComments defined in resolvers, but not in schema
[0]     at addResolversToSchema
```

How can I properly query for sub fields using the Apollo Recommended approach of using `(parent, args, context, info)` arguments where `parent` should be the related user initially queried for when trying to get comments? This way I don't stitch together db queries at the orm level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the examples in apollo server doc, on [how to implement resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/)

In the schema you have already included `comments` property to the `User` type

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String!

  "List of comments authored by the user (optional)"
  comments: [Comment]

  # ... other fields
}
```

you also defined `userByEmail` to fetch user in top-level type `Query`

```
type Query {
  userByEmail(email: String): User!
}
```

Next, you need to implement resolvers for this schema. For the type `Query` you need to implement resolver for the method `userByEmail`. You've done this part

```js
import { getUserByEmail } from '../../dataAccessLayer/orm/user';
import { User } from '../../generated/types';

// Use intersection type to combine Resolvers and Query
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    userByEmail: async (_, { email }: { email: string }) => {
      console.log('parent', email);
      const user = await getUserByEmail(email); // Already includes comments
      return user;
    },
  },
};
```

The next thing you need to do, is to define resolver for `comments` property of `User`, which give you exactly what you want: user comments.

```js
import { getUserByEmail, getCommentsByUserId } from '../../dataAccessLayer/orm/user';
import { User } from '../../generated/types';

// Use intersection type to combine Resolvers and Query
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    userByEmail: async (_, { email }: { email: string }) => {
      const user = await getUserByEmail(email); // Already includes comments
      return user;
    },
  },
  // User. not Comment. 
  User: {
    // The parent entity for comments field is user
    comments: async (parent: User, _: any) {
      if (parent.comments !== undefined) {
         // you mentioned that user fetched with userByEmail already 
         // includes comments, so you might not even need to refetch it
         return parent.comments 
      } 
      const comments = await getCommentsByUserId(user.id)
      return comments;
    },
  }
};
```

And this is an example of the query compatible with our schema

```
query userWithComments($email: String!) {
  userByEmail(email: $email) {
    id
    username
    # some other fields
    comments {
      id
      content   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: LEGEND, yep that was the issue. I was adding Comment as the top level query instead of User, I appreciate your time! Thank you so much!